# How put all the words from a docx file to a dictonary

Tags: c#, dictionary, ms-word, docx

I want to extract all the words from a docx (WORD) file and put them in a dictionary, there are all values of the dictionary because I tried to put them as keys but sometimes in a docx file there are same words.

```
 ` Dictionary <int, string> motRap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Document document = application.Documents.Open("test.docx");

        // Loop through all words in the document.
        int count = document.Words.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            string text = document.Words[i].Text;
            motRap.Add(i, text);

        }
        // Close word.
        application.Quit();
        foreach(var o in motRap)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.Value);
        }`
```

When I try this with a small docx file it works but now when I try with a bigger docx file it says that there is an unhandled exception. Is there a better way to extract words from a docx file?

Comment: Can you catch the exception to see what it is?

Comment: Since you seem to be new here, please try to remember to always, *always* include the error message in your question when you get an exception. Also, take the time to look at the `Data` property of the exception that gets thrown, because sometimes it gives useful information. Another tool at your disposal is the `InnerException` property: if it's not `null`, it can reveal more details about what went wrong.

Comment: The message error is : "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : the filter of the messages point that the application was busy. (Exception of HRESULT : 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)) to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.get_Words() ; to test.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs: line 42

Comment: Thank you for the tips yes i am new and i'm french so my english is not very good (sorry)

Comment: Is this `string text = document.Words[i].Text;` line 42?

Comment: yes it's string text = document.Words[i].Text;

Comment: Can you try to use a `.doc` instead of a `.docx`?

Comment: The problem is when i create a Word file , it become a docx file , and i'm coding for a friend who uses Word.

Comment: You can save it as a `.doc` by using the `save as` option. It's just for testing purposes now

Comment: I use Word 2013 so when i save as file.doc it won't do it and the file stays as docx. I can save as Odt also but it won't allow me to save as doc

Comment: Well.. I only have a couple years of experience so neither of those solutions might be 'good', but you can either use the [DocX library](http://docx.codeplex.com/) that doesn't use COM libraries (there is your error, because the application is busy) and doesn't even need working Word or you could `Sleep` as long as you get the COMException (really not recommended)